# Java final classes used as constants stays after compile

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, constants

I'm using a `final` class as a constant holder for my `static final` variables. I have created my `final` class as shown below.

```
public final class ColorShape {
    public static final int CIRCLE = 1, SQUARE = 2;
}
```

So this should be used as a constant and be deleted after the code gets compiled into an android apk or a java jar.

That is almost half true since the class stays after I compile it to an android apk.

This is what I see after I decompile my android apk

```
public final class ColorShape {

}
```

Edit: I also tried using the keyword abstract instead of final and it was the same result as it would end up with

```
public abstract class ColorShape {

}
```

my `final ints` are gone but the class isn't gone, Is there a reason to why this happens or how I can prevent this? I would like to get rid of the class as well.

Comment: This is a very weird behaviour.

Comment: @Taslim I am wondering how I could make the compiler remove the class now since java won't remove it after its compiled, I think maybe gradle can do this?

Comment: Since it's android, I'd suggest using another memory type like Sharedpreferences. It's more guaranteed to retain your constants although I'm really interested in the reason this method isn't working.

Comment: Is there some Android-specific reason that you expect the class to be removed?  From a general Java perspective, I wouldn't expect that at all.  Of course, I *also* wouldn't expect the variables to be stripped from the class.

Comment: @JohnBollinger No, But I thought it would get removed from my compiled apk since the fields aren't there.

Comment: @Taslim  SharedPreferences are suppose to hold small settings, Like boolean ref or a String that you need ref of, It's used to save states of preferences, Wouldn't make sense to store constants on it since constants are an one time thing that doesn't needs to be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have disabled my `Zelix KlassMaster` obfuscation and the fields don't get stripped away from the classes anymore so it's pretty clear that `Zelix Klassmaster` is removing the field and not the classes. So I dug deeper into my `Zelix Klassmaster` config and saw that I was excluding the classes to be trimmed. and thats the reason they weren't being stripped away like the fields.

```
trimExclude             
package*.^* and
package*.*^ *(*);
```

What I don't get is why the `ChangeLog` didn't print out that Zelix was removing the fields. The ChangeLog just showed that there were no `fieldsOf` my class if anyone can clear this up for me in the comments that would be really nice.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out.  Just to bring home the point, however, I emphasize that neither removing the classes themselves nor removing any fields from them is a behavior expected from the Java compiler or from default packaging tools.

Comment: The Zelix KlassMaster change log will list changes to names and signatures made by Zelix KlassMaster's obfuscation. However, classes, fields and methods which are removed by the Zelix KlassMaster Trim functionionality will be listed in the ZKM_TrimLog.txt file. If you use the "-v" (i.e. verbose) option then they would also be listed in the main ZKM_log.txt file.

Answer (score 0):

I think it gets removed by ProGuard.

Quote from https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code:

> Code shrinking is available with ProGuard, which detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes from your packaged app,...

Comment: I'm not using proguard, I am using Zelix KlassMaster and the class doesn't get deleted so that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Is the field referenced by another class? I don't know Zelix KlassMaster, but according to the doc it also removes unsued fields, classes,...

Comment: Sure it does, It's an obfuscator and shrinker but the question is why doesn't it strip the classes and why only the fields?

Comment: I don't know why it only removes the field. But if the constant is referenced by another class, maybe the tool replaces the value in the referencing class directly with the constant value..

Comment: Look at my answer. I was being confused because the ChangeLog didn't show it was removing the field